# Determining overlap of rotated squares in a detector system

Tags: python, arrays, rotation, detection, overlap

I'm working on a problem which requires me to calculate the overlapping area of two squares. 
This is part of a program which places a rotated detector consisting of several square detector cells/pixels (array) on top of an input map consisting of several (smaller) square pixels and determining the percentage of light from each input pixel detected by the detector pixels.
I've tried a geometric approach, but there's just so many possible variations to account for.

One square can be rotated over a random angle compared to the other, and both squares can be of different sizes. The parameters given are the center coordinates of the detector pixels on the input map, the size of the detector pixels (that of the input pixels is equal to 1 by default) and the rotation angle.

Edit: added a sketch to clarify

[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY7sc.jpg)

So what I'm trying to do is calculate the part of each input pixel (black squares) which lies within a given detector pixel (red square), which can be anywhere between 0 and 1. 
This can then be multiplied with the input pixel's value and summed over all of the input pixels to calculate the total light collected by the detector pixel.

The geometrical approach I've tried using, was calculating the slopes of the detector pixel edges and using the intersect with the input pixel edges to calculate the total overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you're doing is equivalent to trying to find overlapping squares on a grayscale bitmap? If so can you do corner detection, and try to make squares from the detected corners, and then calculates the overlap on the detected squares? This opencv sample might be a good starting point: https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/python/squares.py?rev=907

Apologies in advance if I've misunderstood the question (I am confused by the rotation angle, for instance).

Comment: Not really. I've added a sketch of the problem to clarify the rotation angle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I would use to do this.

1. Make sure you have coordinates for the corners of both squares.
2. Pick *either* square
3. Rotate the cordinates of the corners of *both squares* so that the square you picked in step one has sides parallel to the x and y axis
4. Check if the corners of the other square are inside the first. Since you rotated, this is as simple as checking if the x coordinate is between the left and right sides, and the y coordinate is between the top and bottom.

To rotate the points, you'll use a function something like this:

```
from math import sin, cos, radians

def rotate_points(x, y, angle):
    """Rotate a set of points `angle` degrees counterclockwise about
    the origin.
    """
    theta = radians(angle)
    x_prime = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta)
    y_prime = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta)
    return x_prime, y_prime
```

Comment: This would indeed check if there's a possible overlap, however I need to be able to calculate the total overlap.